# QueueReceiver receive() does not receive messages

Tags: java, jms, weblogic

I've created a synchronous QueueReceiver attached to a WebLogic queue.

```
doStuff() {
  ctx = new InitialContext();
  qconFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup(CONNECTION_FACTORY);
  queue = (Queue) ctx.lookup(outputFromOrcSyncQueue);
  queueConnection = qconFactory.createQueueConnection();
  queueSession = queueConnection.createQueueSession(true, -1);
  queueReceiver = queueSession.createReceiver(queue);
  Message message = queueReceiver.receive();
  ...
}
```

`true` in queueSession creation it's is because the connection factory is transacted.
If i create a no transacted queueSession (by putting `false`) the result is that the queueReceiver seems to ignore the `receive()` method going through the `doStuff` method (same behaviour using `receive(timeout)`, it does not wait before going through).

I've also had to enable [Prefetch Mode for Synchronous Consumer](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/ConsoleHelp/pagehelp/JMSjmsconnectionjmsconnectionfactoryconfigclientparamstitle.html#jms.connection.jmsconnectionfactoryconfigclientparams.synchronousprefetchmode.label) on my connection factory (Client tab in WebLogic connection factory's configuration).

My problem is the receiver does not read any message sent to the queue.

I can see my messages on WebLogic console, I can even see my queueReceiver listening on the queue, but the queueReceiver seems to ignore them.

Alternatives ways I've tried:

- Changing ACK type in queueSession creation (both sides, producer and consumer)
- Commit the session on producer after `send()` and before `close()`

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to call the `start` method on the `QueueConnection`:

```
queueConnection = qconFactory.createQueueConnection();
queueConnection.start();
queueSession = queueConnection.createQueueSession(true, -1);
```

As [The JMS API Programming Model](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnceh.html) in the Java EE Tutorial helpfully says:

> Before your application can consume messages, you must call the connection’s `start` method.

The [JMS Message Consumers](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnceh.html#bncep) section makes it more clear:

> Remember always to call the `start` method; forgetting to start the connection is one of the most common JMS programming errors.